# best mobile phone for app test in india

Tags: android

which mobile phone in india is best for application testing devloped in eclipse and android sdk.i had developed many of application which is based on android 2.2 and some in some i use target as google api 10  then which mobile phone is best for near future in android app development.......................
.....................
/////////////////

```
target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:10
and
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>

GeoPoint  point5 = 
   new GeoPoint((int) (Double.parseDouble(name) * 1E6),
                            (int) (Double.parseDouble(name1) * 1E6));
OverlayItem overlayItem4 = 
   new OverlayItem(point5, sitesList.getGalleryname().get(i)+ "--"+
     sitesList.getAddress().get(i),sitesList.getImagesurl().get(i));

itemizedOverlay3.addOverlay(overlayItem4);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTC Wildfire, Samsung Galaxy 3

Comment: htc wildfire is android2.1... is it good to buy 2.1 when 2.2 is available in market for testing purpose?????my range of price is 20-30 k which will be best in 2.2 version????

Comment: @Atul, when you buy HTC Wildfire, it will be loaded with android 2.1, but the upgrade to android 2.2 is already available :). Or you can go with LG Optimus One, if you want something pre-loaded with Android 2.2.

Comment: LG Optimus One = Rs 12,000 &
HTC Wildfire = Rs 13,000 .... If you like my answer, can you please vote it up and also accept it as a solution (by clicking the check mark )